# Get related entity statecode value to use as a check

Tags: c#, plugins, entity, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to be able to only execute my code upon the condition that the related opportunity has a `statecode` of `1`

In my code I am able to use the [GenerateSalesOrderFromOpportunityRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.generatesalesorderfromopportunityrequest.aspx) class provided by the Microsoft Dynamics SDK to create a new sales order when a opportunityclose activity is created.

The drawback of this approach is that an `opportunityclose` activity is created by the system when an opportunity is closed as won(`1`) or lost(`2`). Also, there are no attributes on the `opportunityclose` activity that say if it was won or lost. So the only way to find it out is to get that attribute from the related opportunity.

In my code I'm able to get other attributes from the related opportunity, like `name`, but I have not been able to get any other value for `statecode` other that `0`.

Here is my code:

```
Entity postImageEntity = (context.PostEntityImages != null && context.PostEntityImages.Contains(this.postImageAlias)) ? context.PostEntityImages[this.postImageAlias] : null;

            if (postImageEntity.LogicalName == "opportunityclose" && postImageEntity.Attributes.Contains("opportunityid") && postImageEntity.Attributes["opportunityid"] != null)
            {
                // Create an entity reference for the related opportunity to get the id for the GenerateSalesOrderFromOpportunityRequest class
                EntityReference entityRef = (EntityReference)postImageEntity.Attributes["opportunityid"];

                // Retrieve the opportunity that the closed opportunity activity was created for.
                Entity RelatedEntityRef = service.Retrieve("opportunity", entityRef.Id, new ColumnSet( new String[] {"statecode","statuscode", "name"}));

                OptionSetValue StateCode = (OptionSetValue)RelatedEntityRef.Attributes["statecode"];

                OptionSetValue StatusCode = (OptionSetValue)RelatedEntityRef.Attributes["statuscode"];

                string OppName = (string)RelatedEntityRef.Attributes["name"];

                if (entityRef.LogicalName == "opportunity" && StateCode.Value == 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        GenerateSalesOrderFromOpportunityRequest req = new GenerateSalesOrderFromOpportunityRequest();
                        req.OpportunityId = entityRef.Id;
                        req.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
                        GenerateSalesOrderFromOpportunityResponse resp = (GenerateSalesOrderFromOpportunityResponse)service.Execute(req);
                    }
                    catch (FaultException ex)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Recap: For this to work I just need to be able to get the actual `statecode` value of the `opportunity` related to the `opportunityclose`. Currently I have only been able to get `0` even if I know that the state code of the opportunity is `1`.

Other Info:

- This is for Microsoft Dynamics Online 2013/2015(works with both)
- Using SKD v6.1.1
- Plugin works, but fires whether the opportunity is won or lost. (not intended)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you view the opportunity to see if the status is won or lost.  I

You can retrieve the OpportunityClose and change the status if you need to 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334301.aspx

I assume it's setting the opportunityclose to 1 because you are executing GenerateSalesOrderFromOpportunityRequest which you would only do if you won the opportunity (e.g. you wouldn't progress a lost opportunity).

Comment: I originally tried to execute the plugin on the `Win` message of the opportunity, but when using that message it won't let you use a `postentityimage` to get the id of the opportunity id. So I ran it on the `opportuntiyclose` activity which works.

However, when I try to pull in the `statecode`(status)of the opportunity to see if it was won or lost I get a `0` every time.

In the code above, this is what I use to get the state code. Does this look wrong?
`OptionSetValue StateCode = (OptionSetValue)RelatedEntityRef.Attributes["statecode"];`